# UILabel repeatedly fade between two text strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, fade, repeat

I'm new to iOS programming...I'm trying to animate the transition between two text strings within a single label when the user taps a button.

So far - I seem to have the fading working suitably using nested / multistage block animations. Yet even with `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` & `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` it refuses to repeat itself continuously (until the user taps another button). Any ideas?! Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)FadeButtonPress:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{ _FadeLabel.text = @"AAAA";
                     [_FadeLabel setAlpha:1.0f ]; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                           delay:0
                                         options: nil
                                      animations:^{ [_FadeLabel setAlpha:0.0f]; }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                delay:0
                                                              options: nil
                                                           animations:^{_FadeLabel.text = @"BBBB";
                                                               [_FadeLabel setAlpha:1.0f ]; }
                                                           completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                               [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                                     delay:0
                                                                                   options: nil
                                                                                animations:^{ [_FadeLabel setAlpha:0.0f]; }
                                                                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                                                                                         }]; }]; }]; }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)FadeButtonPress:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

    if ([_labe.text isEqualToString:@"Text 1"]) {
        [_labe setText:@"Text 2"];
    } else {
        [_labe setText:@"Text 1"];
    }
    [self.labe setAlpha: 1];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.labe setAlpha: 0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self FadeButtonPress:sender];
    }];

}];
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! Is there a way to repeat this without the [self FadeButtonPress:sender]; at the end? The same button is doing a whole heap of other stuff...